# Hide refrence search action on Openxava, How To?

Tags: openxava

I need to display all item in my view readonly except one field and between all field there is one reference field and I would like to hide the reference search action of that field in openxava. How can i do it? If it's not possible, then how to simulate that?

Answer (score 0):

Annotate all the elements you want read only with @ReadOnly.
You can also do it programmatically from a on-init action using getView().setEditable("memberName", false)